# View is not visible while using it with include tag

Tags: android, xml, view, include

I am having a layout `activity_main.xml` which adds another layout (`login_screen.xml` `signup_screen.xml`) using `include` tag. The layout which is added using `include` tag has a view component which is declared using `View`. That View is visible in their respective layouts,(`login_screen.xml` `signup_screen.xml`), but while adding into `activity_main.xml` `View` becomes invisible. I tried copying the entire code and pasting it in `activity_main.xml`, at that time `View` visible.

What is the actual issue? Could someone please help me out?

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/login_screen"
            android:id="@+id/login_screen"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/signup_screen"
            android:id="@+id/signup_screen"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/as_guest"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

login_screen.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <View
          android:layout_width="2dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="Username" />

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hintt="Password"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

signup_screen.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <View
          android:layout_width="2dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="Username" />

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hintt="Password"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT: I have removed all the constraints here for making it easier to read, in my code, I have set the constraints properly and it's perfect.

Comment: Hi Kavin, I am facing the similar issue, could you please update how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you set `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` on the `<include />` tags?

What you're effectively saying right now is "ok, let the width match whatever constraints are set" but there aren't any constraints to match.

Note: For your current XML, you might as well use a `LinearLayout` with the `android:orientation` set to `vertical` - you don't have *any* constraints specified at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply. I tried adding ```match_parent``` still it's looking the same. But while editing ```layout_width=""``` I kept like this ```android:layout_width=""```, at that moment the ```View``` is visible, but the entire layout included in ```include``` tag jumps to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I am not sure what is the problem, but for your usecase, you can use `ViewStub` instead of include

Answer (score 0):

Setting the constraints to the layout of the `<include>` tag works for me

```
  <include
    android:id="@+id/login_screen"
    layout="@layout/login_screen"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/signup_screen"
    layout="@layout/signup_screen"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Are you changing your constraints anywhere in your activity?

Comment: I have added constraints properly, but I haven't mentioned in the question for simplicity. Even I changed the constraints pointing to another view to ```parent``` as you mentioned, but still, it's not visible @yugansh